# Rectangle dimensions relative to other elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I'm preparing a block diagram in tikz as depicted in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFZyZ.png). I made this picture by precisely planning and calculating distances and sizes. However, any change made to this picture could possibly necessitate changes in other components. For example, if I add a component D2 below D, I'd have to adjust the size of E and F accordingly.

My question: **Do you know a way how to solve this more nicely?**

Concretely, I'd like to have a way of creating such diagrams with the following properties:

- The position, height and width of objects can be defined based on edges of other components (e.g., `E.north = B.north; E.south = D.south;`)
- The gray boxes fit exactly their contents
- The maximum size of a white rectangle is 70% of the gray box. Multiple white rectangles in the same row share the available width equally
- The database symbol has a fixed size
- When changing the position of the gray box, its content will also move accordingly
- Central constants, such as box height, node distance, etc. should be defined once and changing a constant should not result in the need of adjusting other values

[image: Architecture diagram]

For illustration purposes of my current approach, this is the code that displays most of the screenshot:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,backgrounds,positioning,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,scale=0.9,->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick,
       component/.style={draw,fill=white,inner xsep=1,minimum height=1.5em,node distance=.25cm and .5cm},
       full/.style={minimum width=9cm},
       full2/.style={minimum width=7.7cm},
       half/.style={minimum width=4.25cm},
       half2/.style={minimum width=3.6cm},
       third/.style={minimum width=2.66cm},
       layer_annot/.style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries,node distance=.5cm},
       layer/.style={fill=lightgray,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=1.5em+.5cm,node distance=.5cm},
       layer2/.style={minimum height=3em+.75cm},
       layer4/.style={minimum height=6em+1.3cm},
       spanv3/.style={minimum height=4.5em+.54cm},
       db/.style={cylinder,draw,shape border rotate=90,fill=white,minimum width=.8cm,minimum height=.4cm,node distance=.5cm and .5cm,yshift=.3cm}]

% background
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[layer,layer4]            (F) {}; 
  \node[layer,above=of F,layer2] (J) {}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}    

% components
\node[component,full,below right=of F.north west]                    (A)  {A}; 
\node[component,half2,below=of A.south east,anchor=north east]       (B)  {B}; 
\node[component,half2,below=of B]                                    (C)  {C}; 
\node[component,half2,below=of C]                                    (D)  {D}; 
\node[component,spanv3,half2,left=of B.north west,anchor=north east] (E)  {E}; 
\node[db,left=of E.west]                                             (db) {}; 
\node[component,full,below right=of J.north west]                    (G)  {G}; 
\node[component,third,above right=of J.south west]                   (H)  {H}; 
\node[component,third,right=of H]                                    (I)  {I}; 

% layer names
\node[layer_annot,left=of F.east]   (F_label)   {F}; 
\node[layer_annot,left=of J.east]   (J_label)   {J}; 

% connections
\path[->] ($(db -| E.west)+(0,.1)$) edge ($(db.east)+(0,.1)$)
          ($(db.east)-(0,.1)$) edge ($(db -| E.west)-(0,.1)$)
          ($(B -| E.east)+(0,.1)$) edge ($(B.west)+(0,.1)$)
          ($(B.west)-(0,.1)$) edge ($(B -| E.east)-(0,.1)$)
          % ...
          (E.north) edge (E.north |- A.south)
          (A.north -| H.south) edge (H.south)
          (A.north -| I.south) edge (I.south)
          % ...
          ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. You are already loading `fit` and `backgrounds`, but only use the latter. The big background nodes could be designed to fit the others. Likewise, you could use fit to determine the dimensions of `E`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for mentioning that. I was not aware that `fit` can do more than just fit box sizes to its content. -- In a previous version, I used `fit` to adjust the size of the background according to its content. However, I soon ran into a chicken-egg problem where the position of the elements depend on the gray boxes and the size of the gray boxes depend on the containing elements, but I have to define one element first and cannot refer to non-existing elements. That's why I removed the usage of fit for the gray boxes.

Comment: Another problem that I ran into was the right alignment of the bold text. When I used `fit`, I could not achieve a right alignment of the text for some reason.

Comment: I cannot see any bold text. Yet I had never problems of that kind. Do you achieve the bold text via `font=\bfseries`?

Comment: Yes, `font=\bfseries`. `F` and `J` are considered to be bold. Maybe, it's not clear because they are only single letters.

Comment: But I cannot see any problem with these.

Comment: I had a problem with those when I used `fit` to adjust the size of the gray boxes because I didn't managed to align the text right. The corresponding code does not exist anymore, so it's just a side note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand your last comment. However, this answer addresses how to

1. draw the background rectangles via `fit` and
2. how to make the `E` node as tall the `B`, `C` and `D` nodes by using `calc`. (Notice that there is a hardcoded `0.9` which can be eliminated by using transform shape, but I do not know the purpose of `scale=0.9` in you picture so I went this way).

Here's the code. I didn't have to add any library as you were loading but not using `fit` and `calc`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,backgrounds,positioning,arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,scale=0.9,->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick,
       component/.style={draw,fill=white,inner xsep=1,minimum height=1.5em,node distance=.25cm and .5cm},
       full/.style={minimum width=9cm},
       full2/.style={minimum width=7.7cm},
       half/.style={minimum width=4.25cm},
       half2/.style={minimum width=3.6cm},
       third/.style={minimum width=2.66cm},
       layer_annot/.style={font=\footnotesize\bfseries,node distance=.5cm},
       layer/.style={fill=lightgray,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=1.5em+.5cm,node distance=.5cm},
       layer2/.style={minimum height=3em+.75cm},
       layer4/.style={minimum height=6em+1.3cm},
       spanv3/.style={minimum height=4.5em+.54cm},
       db/.style={cylinder,draw,shape border rotate=90,fill=white,minimum width=.8cm,minimum height=.4cm,node distance=.5cm and .5cm,yshift=.3cm}]


% components
\node[component,full] at (0,0)                    (A)  {A}; 
\node[component,half2,below=of A.south east,anchor=north east]       (B)  {B}; 
\node[component,half2,below=of B]                                    (C)  {C}; 
\node[component,half2,below=of C]                                    (D)  {D};
\path let \p1=($(B.north)-(D.south)$) in \pgfextra{\typeout{\y1}}
node[component,minimum height=0.9*\y1,inner ysep=0pt,half2,left=of B.north west,anchor=north east] (E)  {E}; 
\node[db,left=of E.west]                                             (db) {}; 
\node[component,third,above=1.6cm of A.west,anchor=west]               (H)  {H}; 
\node[component,third,right=of H]                                    (I)  {I}; 
\node[component,full,above=8mm of H.west,anchor=west]                    (G)  {G}; 



% background
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \path ([xshift=3cm]D.east) coordinate(auxD) ([xshift=3cm]G.east) coordinate
  (auxG);   
  \node[layer,fit=(A) (D) (auxD),layer4]  (F) {}; 
  \node[layer,fit=(G) (H) (auxG),layer2] (J) {}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}    

% layer names
\node[layer_annot,left=of F.east]   (F_label)   {F}; 
\node[layer_annot,left=of J.east]   (J_label)   {J}; 

% connections
\path[->] ($(db -| E.west)+(0,.1)$) edge ($(db.east)+(0,.1)$)
          ($(db.east)-(0,.1)$) edge ($(db -| E.west)-(0,.1)$)
          ($(B -| E.east)+(0,.1)$) edge ($(B.west)+(0,.1)$)
          ($(B.west)-(0,.1)$) edge ($(B -| E.east)-(0,.1)$)
          % ...
          (E.north) edge (E.north |- A.south)
          (A.north -| H.south) edge (H.south)
          (A.north -| I.south) edge (I.south)
          % ...
          ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. This solves the problem with the box heights and widths. The `scale=0.9` is there for historical reasons, it has no special intention. I'll remove it.